# How to make \tikz object to appear in the same slide as \tikzmarkin<>

Tags: hf-tikz

Maybe somebody could give me a solution. I want to make as it is shown in the picture to appear in different slides (not repeating the code)[image: tikzmarkin].

I want matrix without any highlights to appear in the first slide, then blue highlights and arrow in the second slide, and the third slide has to have the view as shown in the picture. 
I can get this sequence for  \tikzmarkin objects just if I write the number of slide in the brackets <>. But I have no idea how to do this with the arrows.

Thanks very much for any help,
Rasa

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\[
\mathbf{G}:=\left[\begin{array}{cc}  
\tikzmarkin<1,2,3>[set fill color=blue!50!cyan!30,
 set border color=blue!40!black]{a}g_{11} & \tikzmarkin<1>[set fill color=green!50!lime!30,
 set border color=green!40!black]{b}g_{12}\\  g_{21} \tikzmarkend{a} & g_{22}\tikzmarkend{b} \end{array}\right]=
 \left[\begin{array}{cc} \tikzmarkin<1>[set fill color=blue!50!cyan!30,
  set border color=blue!40!black]{c}{\mathbf{G}_{1}}
  \tikzmarkend{c}
  & \tikzmarkin<1>[set fill color=green!50!lime!30,
  set border color=green!40!black]{d}\mathbf{G}_{2}\tikzmarkend{d}     \end{array}\right].
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw [blue,-stealth]     ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]a.east) to [out=35,in=145]    ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]c.east);}
 \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw [green,-stealth]     ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]b.east) to [out=35,in=145]   ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]d.east);}
 \]
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
 \usepackage[customcolors,beamer]{hf-tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

 \begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\[
\mathbf{G}:=\left[\begin{array}{cc}  
  \tikzmarkin<1,2>[set fill color=blue!50!cyan!30, set border color=blue!40!black] {a} g_{11}  &
  \tikzmarkin<1>[set fill color=green!50!lime!30, set border color=green!40!black]{b}g_{12} \\
  g_{21} \tikzmarkend{a} &  g_{22} \tikzmarkend{b} 
\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 
  \tikzmarkin<1>[set fill color=blue!50!cyan!30, set border color=blue!40!black]{c} \mathbf{G}_{1} \tikzmarkend{c}
  & \tikzmarkin<1>[set fill color=green!50!lime!30, set border color=green!40!black]{d} \mathbf{G}_{2} \tikzmarkend{d} 
\end{array}\right].
\only<1> {\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw [blue,-stealth]
           ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]a.east) to [out=35,in=145]([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]c.east);}
         \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw [green,-stealth]
           ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]b.east) to [out=35,in=145]([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=0.5mm]d.east);}}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, after some changes in Your code I got exactly what I wanted:)

Comment: Since John's answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).